# What is a single word to describe someone who has very little or no authority?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word to describe someone who has very little or no authority? An older colleague used to say it but I cannot recall.

Comment: Perhaps 'gofer' if their job is one with little or no authority.

Comment: Do you mean someone who **thinks** they have authority but actually do not?

Comment: ***Underling**?*

Comment: Perhaps 'submissive', 'docile'?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could call this person a peon.

Comment: Your answer should demonstrate a source.  Citing a source will give an answer more credibility.

Answer (score 0):

my favorite: dilettante.  other favs include apprentice, beginner, neophyte, novice, dabbler, layman, & nonprofessional.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/authority